# Using a CDN for a mobile Swift app

Tags: swift

I am currently developing a mobile app using Swift and wondering if someone could give their opinion about whether or not using a CDN is a good idea for some app images?

What I mean is, in the app the user will be able to achieve milestones/badges. The designs may change over time and I was thinking instead of embedding these in the app, put them on to a CDN and allow the app to call the CDN when needed and cache the response.

My concern with this is that in the app I provide 3 different sizes for each image and the app determines which size to use based on the users device. How would this work with online/CDN images? I don't really want to be downloading the largest image if I only need the smallest one.

I will be needing to store the profile image in a CDN so I need to go through the setup regardless but just didn't know about whats best practice for other app images. Things like tab images and other basic icons I will embed in the app but what about the images a user can achieve?

I realise this could be to broad a question and come down to personal opinion but really looking for some thoughts and if someone has come across the same "problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) is what you need.

Comment: This looks perfect. Would this mean if the designs of the badges change I would need to upload a new version of the app to the app store?